# adding js file in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I have two questions.
First, where should I put a JavaScript file to make it global across all pages?
Second, let's say there is a module called "module-layered-navigation," and I want to override it in my theme and add a JavaScript file specifically for this module. How can I achieve this, ensuring that the JavaScript file is only readable within this module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Overriding the Magento Js:

If you want to override Magento_Customer JS file, Just create the directory with the Magento_Customer name and place the JS file as place in the vendor similar like directory structure apply your changes in the code it will works.

For adding JS file in accross all pages magento 2, you can follow this link:

https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-js-file-in-frontend-for-all-pages-in-magento-2/